# How to transfer an ERC1155 Matic token using Node.js?

Tags: nodejs, transfer, erc-1155, polygon, opensea

I'm trying to write a Node script that will transfer an ERC1155 token on the Matic network from my address to someone else's address.

Here's an example token:
https://opensea.io/assets/matic/0x2953399124f0cbb46d2cbacd8a89cf0599974963/72846082262473004479256831974008120683339732829716081255357396830225176237696

I thought I could just use https://github.com/maticnetwork/matic.js, but it seems to only work for ERC20/ERC721 tokens.

I then played around with https://docs.moralis.io/moralis-server/sending-assets#transferring-erc1155-tokens-semi-fungible, but I can't figure out how to authenticate it using web3 or truffle + my wallet mnemonic. Moralis seems like it's meant for frontend authentication (ie MetaMask Chrome Extension), but I need this to work with backend code.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance!